Where is the story of sage angiras being the mentor of shukracharya (and shukra leaving during to the sage being biased to his son?)
This is my first question, so I beg your pardon if I didn't phrase it correctly.
Ok so a lot of websites on the net (example) say this both guru and shukra were the disciples of sage angiras, but the latter "dropped out" and continued his studies near sage Gautama because of the favourism the sage showed for his son brihaspati.
Now I do know that sage angiras WAS the guru of shukracharya, at least that is what the kacha-devayani dialogue suggests:

Kacha replied, 'Thou art to me an object of regard and worship even as thy father! O thou of faultless features, thou art, indeed, even an object of greater reverence! Thou art dearer than life to the high-souled Bhargava, O amiable one! As the daughter of my preceptor, thou art ever worthy of my worship! As my preceptor Sukra, thy father, is ever deserving of my regards, so art thou, O Devayani! Therefore, it behoveth thee not to say so.' Hearing this, Devayani replied, 'Thou, too, art the son of my father's preceptor's son. Therefore, O best of Brahmanas, thou art deserving of my regards and worship. O Kacha, when thou wert slain so many times by the Asuras, recollect today the affection I showed for thee. Remembering my friendship and affection for thee, and, indeed, my devoted regard also, O virtuous one, it behoveth thee not to abandon me without any fault. I am truly devoted to thee.'

Adding onto this the wisomlib website says this about usanas:

The preceptor of the Daityas and Asuras;1 on Śiśumāracakra;2 disciple of the father of Bṛhaspati and leader of a side of Soma (Pārṣṇi);3 father of Devayānī; by his curse Yayātī could not enjoy his youth to the full and hence requested his sons to give their youth in exchange for his old age.4 Praised Amarakaṇṭakakṣetra;5 a sage;6 see śukra.

Wisdomlib here cites the vayu purana (90.30 to be more precise) and some other texts. But in the version of vayu purana I'm using there isn't a chapter 90...
So yes I'd appreciate if there's actually a proper chapter/verse where all of this is mentioned.
Also that "sage angiras being biased" story thing — some of these websites say that this story is in the devi bhagavata purana but I was unable to find it as far as I searched.
Thanks in advance.
